# Nested states generate wrong base path

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create nested states of multiple levels. Unfortunately, something seems to be wrong. In any state, when you refresh the browser, everything works fine. Except in the `app.admin.training` state: 
the console shows me that the css files could not be found (showing a wrong path: `localhost/admin/node_modules/...` instead of `localhost/node_modules/...`).

Here's my ui-router configuration:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/login.view.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl',
    })
    .state('app', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/app.view.html',
        controller: 'appCtrl',
        abstract: true,
    })
    .state('app.dashboard', {
        url: 'dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/dash.view.html',
        controller: 'dashCtrl',
    })
    .state('app.admin', {
        url: 'admin',
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
    })
    .state('app.admin.training', {
        url: 'training',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/admin/training/main.view.html',
        controller: 'mainTrainingCtrl',
    });
```

I tried adding a `/` after `admin` which doesn't help, same thing by adding it in front of the `training` state.

Now after crawling through google, I couldn't find anything to solve this !

Comment: how are you loading css state-wise?

Comment: in my index.html file, that part is static. The controllers are loaded dynamically using oclazyload (and they work no matter what)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that my stylesheets were loaded with a relative path.
I just added a `/` in front of the URL and it works out as expected again.

Just in case someone else stumbles upon this !